# Как скачать файл с локального сервера js

Tags: javascript

В общем, суть такая. Я только начал изучать web.
Я разворачиваю сервер на yarn у себя на компьютере. Там небольшой html и js. И хочу чтоб, при входе на этот сервер с телефона(например) в локальной сети, начиналось скачивание определенного файла с хранилища компьютера.
Как мне это сделать?

У меня уже есть вот такой код

```
var saveByteArray = (function () {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    return function (data, name) {
        var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/octet-binary"}),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = name;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
}());
saveByteArray([sampleBytes], 'example.txt');
```

он сохраняет в файл данные из массива. Я конечно могу написать приложение, которое превратит бинарный файл в массив js, но мне кажется, должно быть более адекватное решение. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: не понятно, чего Вы добиваетесь

Comment: а сервер у Вас готов отдать "файл с хранилища компьютера"?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я хочу, чтоб у меня в локальной сети стоял компьютер, и при вводе его ip-адреса в строке браузера начиналось скачивание определенного файла. Возможно я вообще все неправильно делаю, в таком случае подскажите, как правильно))

Comment: @Дмытрык ну я не знаю)) А что нужно сделать, чтоб он был готов?

Comment: @slavaguk должен сохраниться js файл на диск компьютера клиента?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ нет, не js. У меня есть .apk файл, который люди должны скачивать на свои телефоны в локальной сети. Мне показалось самым простым, чтоб люди вводили только ip-адрес компьютера. Но я не знаю, как реализовать это.

Comment: @slavaguk  а просто переход по ссылке работает как-то не так?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ извините за глупый вопрос, но по какой ссылке?

Comment: Вы разместили файл на сервере, по какому адресу?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я просто на своем ноутбуке на винде yarn запустил. Когда с телефона ввожу локальный ip компа, вижу html страничку моего сайта. И при этом хочу, чтоб начиналось скачивание apk файла.

Comment: положите рядом с html страничкой этот apk файл и в строке браузера неберите https://192.168.0.X/yourfile.apk

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Спасибо большое. Я не знал, что оно так работает) 
Это уже пойдет как решение, но может есть еще возможность, чтоб все таки вводить только ip, а оно по умолчанию дописывало "/yourfile.apk"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет необходимости что-то изобретать, за Вас все может сделать браузер.

1. Положите рядом с `index.html` страничкой этот `yourfile.apk` файл и в строке браузера наберите https://192.168.0.X/yourfile.apk
2. Чтобы не набирать имя файла, можно организовать редирект из index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/yourfile.apk" />
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```